# Что означает idl-атрибут в спецификации html5?

Tags: html, css, html5, веб-программирование, idl

В спецификации html5 часто встречается понятие idl-атрибут. 
Например, из описания атрибута title

> "The title IDL attribute must reflect the title content attribute"

Примерный перевод:
"idl-атрибут title должен отображать содержимое атрибута title"

Совершенно не понимаю, что означает эта фраза? Причем тут idl и какое отношение idl имеет к html? Я думал idl - это совершенно иной язык.

Или, например, атрибут style.

> "The style IDL attribute is defined in the CSS Object Model (CSSOM)
>   specification"

Примерный перевод: "idl-атрибуту style дано определение в спецификации CSS Object Model (CSSOM) specification"

Понятно, что этому атрибуту дано определение в такой-то спецификации, но что это за атрибут? для чего он нужен, что дает? и какое отношение имеет к спецификации html?

Comment: IDL атрибут - это атрибут в виде свойства javascript, Отражает или соответствует атрибуту элемента. дано `<input maxlength="123"> `. Имеется атрибут `maxlength`. Достанем его так:`element.getAttribute("maxlength")`. А можно через IDL-атрибут -  `element.maxlength`. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B6.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.B2_.D1.81.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B8_.D1.81_IDL_.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.B1.D1.83.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B8

Comment: все равно что-то не догоняю. какое отношение idl имеет к html спецификации? как он реально используется в html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Во-первых**, мир веба постоянно меняется, постоянно появляются новые фичи, которые надо бы специфицировать. Количество спек разрослось, и вот для того чтобы как-то унифицировать понятия, используемые в разных спецификациях, появилась некая "мета-спека": [`Web-IDL`](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/), Interface Defenition Language for Web. Документ, описывающий как нужно описывать интерфейсы для новых браузерных возможностей. Собственно понятие IDL-атрибут оттуда и берется.

**Во-вторых**, в вебе довольно часта ситуация сначала появляются фичи, и только когда фичи все давно используют, под них пишется спека. Которая просто берет что есть и описывает формально. То есть по сути спека большее время на развитие фичи не влияет.

**В результате** у нас есть некий интерфейс. Те самые IDL - атрибуты.
И есть реальный мир.
И надо бы эти две вещи как-то познакомить между собой, а то нехорошо получается.
Приведенные вами строки этим и занимаются.

**Примеры:**
Допустим
у вас есть в html
 `<p id = "someid" title = "trololo" style="background:red">sometext</p>`

**По первой выделенной строчке:**
Что вы получите когда напишете
    `document.getElementById('someid').title`?
Вот строка спеки и говорит о том, что "не волнуйся парень, то что ты в теге написал для title и то что ты получить пытаешься, это одно и то же"

> "The title IDL attribute must reflect the title content attribute"

**По второй выделенной строчке**

> "The style IDL attribute is defined in the CSS Object Model (CSSOM)
>   specification"

Что ты реально получишь обратившись сделав `document.getElementById('someid').style`  - смотри в спеке по цсс.