# Почему, если задать в <form> инлайновый обработчик события, то через него можно обратится к элементам формы по name?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Пример кода:

```
<form onkeydown='console.log(name)'>
<input type='text' name='name' value='Василиса'>
<input type='text' name='age' value='secret'>
</form>
```

Выводит в консоль:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="Василиса">
```

Как это работает?
Если обработчик повесить отдельно, то такого эффекта уже нету.

Comment: Возможно, при такой записи, объект `this` берет одно значение, при другой записи - другое...?

Comment: Если вкратце, то "так написано где-то в спеке". Но конкретные строчки спеки я гуглю уже минут 15))

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Еще бы не написано:) Я тоже пытался найти) Есть мысль что это как-то связано с form.elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы ответить на вопрос, нам надо понять:

1. **Почему инлайн обработчики и обычные ведут себя по разному?**
   Подробно описано [**в этом разделе спецификации.**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers)
   Инлайн обработчик, это вообще говоря еще не скрипт, в скрипт его еще предстоит превратить. И как это делается - описано в спецификации **[вот здесь](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler).** Обратите внимание на пункт 10:

> **Lexical Environment Scope**
>     **1.** Let Scope be the result of NewObjectEnvironment(document, the global environment).
>     **2.** If form owner is not null, let Scope be the result of NewObjectEnvironment(>form
>   owner, Scope).
>     **3.** If element is not null, let Scope be the result of
>   NewObjectEnvironment(element, Scope).

То есть в наше лексическое окружение (простым языком - переменные доступные в функции) внезапно подмешиваются "переменные формы" именно здесь.

2. **Что это такое за "переменные формы" такие**?
   Откуда в них берутся имена инпутов если я не писал их прямо в теге form?

Когда ты делаешь скажем `document.getElementById('someid')` то получаешь не просто строчку html же, а некоторую странную штуку у которой бывают неожиданные свойства.

Так вот, эта штука - это отдельный слой абстракции. 
Именно на этом уровне "объект" формы обогащается свойствами, содержащими ссылки на связанные с ним контролы (и всякими другими полезными вещами).

В спецификации если нужно узнать что в этом объекте будет - обычно нужно искать по ключевым словам "IDL attributes". Я про них [**когда-то здесь отвечал**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527205/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-idl-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-html5/528581#528581), довольно косноязычно правда.

3. **Ок, а где написано что в переменные формы попадают по name?**
   [**В интерфейсе**](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#dom-htmlformelement-__getter__-name-name) который должна реализовывать форма.
   Дальше по ходу раздела 4.10.3 это [**декларируется более развернуто.**](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#past-names-map)
   Есть специальное "человеческое" пояснение в том же разделе в ненормативной секции:

> form[name] Returns the form control (or, if there are several, a
>   RadioNodeList of the form controls) in the form with the given ID or
>   name (excluding image buttons for historical reasons); or, if there
>   are none, returns the img element with the given ID.
>
> Once an element has been referenced using a particular name, that name
>   will continue being available as a way to reference that element in
>   this method, even if the element’s actual ID or name changes, for as
>   long as the element remains in the Document.
>
> If there are multiple matching items, then a RadioNodeList object
>   containing all those elements is returned.

Кто бы мне сказал лет пять назад, что я буду с огромным интересом на ночь читать хтмл спеку - я бы покрутил крылом у виска.

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой развернутый ответ. Я не настолько опытный чтобы сразу понимать описания спецификаций, но хочется понимать как все работает на более низком уровне :)
И по первому пункту не очень ясно. Т.е. все свойства что доступны по this.свойство, становятся переменными окружения для инлайн обработчиков?

Comment: @A.Gusev, вообще говоря нет. В этом пункте говорится про _создание_ функции-обработчика. Значение this определяется во время _вызова_ этой функции (хотя от способа создания тоже зависит). Здесь говорится про скоуп переменных доступных внутри функции, LexicalEnvironment. Он в ощем с this не связан, хотя в каких-то частных функциях может быть связан. Надо найти раздел спецификации в котором говорится о вызове обработчиков, и закурить в соответствующий раздел js-спеки. Ну то есть это две разные сущности, понимание как они связаны по факту достойно отдельного вопроса кмк.